# Is there a way to Increase HTML5 Storage quota

Tags: html, local-storage, indexeddb, html5-filesystem

I've been trying and searching for a way to increase the native quota on Safari (both iOS & Desktop), and Chrome, I've tried with no success and searched almost everywhere.

I'm working on a web-app that supposed to work offline most of the time, so at the user's first login, I retrieve the contents and store them within pre-defined databases (using IndexedDB), the problem here is that the app's content may be larger than 30MB.

Is there any way to prompt the user to increase his quota so it fits my app's needs, as long as I understand that there's no way to force a specific quota with out his permission ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, I think 30MB will fit into the default. Second, I think the browser will prompt the user if you go over that. Have you tried?

Comment: @torazaburo No the browser doesn't prompt at all, an error gets occurred while filling the database with retrieved content, is there something I am missing here ? to check for the available quota or something like that ?

Answer (score 1):

With Chrome (and soon Firefox) you can use APIs to query the quota and how much is used:

From Chrome M61 on (and future Firefox) - [spec](https://storage.spec.whatwg.org/#api):

```
navigator.storage.estimate().then(
  (used, total) => console.log(
    `using ${used} out of ${total}, or ${used/total*100}%`
  )
);
```

Older Chrome only:

```
navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota(
  (used, total) => console.log(
    `using ${used} out of ${total}, or ${used/total*100}%`)
);
```

How much quota an origin is granted by Chrome varies depending on device storage capacity (to balance multiple competing sites and not fill the device). There is no API or prompt to increase storage.

Safari doesn't support the `estimate()` API yet and likely has different rules/heuristics for granting quota.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you made many things clearer for me, I'd like to mention that I've read answers on other similar posts which says that devices prompts the user to increase the quota when the used storage is full, unfortunately I didn't had the chance ( & contents ) to test that yet, if that exists, does't interrupt the data from being stored or it just puts it on hold till the user grants the increase ?